# string and char incompatibilities

Tags: c++

I am surprised that in C++ there's not a built-in method to cast strings and chars. Here's my issue: I want to update a line in a text file so:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {

  char l1 [12];
  char l2 [15];
  char l3 [15];
  char l4 [15];
  char md [16];

  FILE * myfile2 = fopen("state.txt", "r+");
  fgets(l1,12,myfile2);
  fgets(l2,12,myfile2);
  fgets(l3,12,myfile2);
  fgets(l4,12,myfile2);
  fseek ( myfile2 , 0 , SEEK_SET );

  strcpy(md , "detectoroff");
  fputs (md,myfile2);

  strcpy(md,l2);
  fputs (md,myfile2);
  strcpy(md,l3);
  fputs (md,myfile2);
  strcpy(md,l4);
  fputs (md,myfile2);
  Sleep(1000);
  fclose(myfile2);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Inicially the text file has

```
    a
    b
    c
    d
```

When runs the code the output is

```
detectoroffb
    c
    d
```

and if I replace the line

```
  strcpy(md , "detectoroff");
```

by this

```
  strcpy(md , "detectoroff\n");
```

now the result is ok BUT if I run this twice, appears a empty line under the first one and another if it's run three times etc. How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Has nothing to do with C++ and C++11 (removing this tag). This code is pure C except useless C++ includes.

Comment: What does this have to do with casting strings and chars? What does it have to do with `std::string` at all?

Comment: maybe I should use the word "convert" instead of "cast", convert string to chars is what I further needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't be afraid of using a few kilobytes.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
int main(void) {
  using namespace std;
  static const int BUFFERSIZE = 4096;
  char line_1[BUFFERSIZE];
  char line_2[BUFFERSIZE];
  char line_3[BUFFERSIZE];
  char line_4[BUFFERSIZE];
  char md [] = "detectoroff\n";

  FILE * myfile2 = fopen("state.txt", "r+");

  fgets(line_1, BUFFERSIZE, myfile2);
  fgets(line_2, BUFFERSIZE, myfile2);
  fgets(line_3, BUFFERSIZE, myfile2);
  fgets(line_4, BUFFERSIZE, myfile2);

  fseek(myfile2, 0, SEEK_SET );

  fputs(md, myfile2);
  fputs(line_2, myfile2);
  fputs(line_3, myfile2);
  fputs(line_4, myfile2);

  fclose(myfile2);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Even better is to write this program in C++ instead of the C-style:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main(void) {
  using namespace std;
  string line_1, line_2, line_3, line_4;
  string md("detectoroff");
  fstream myfile2("state.txt", fstream::in|fstream::out);

  getline(myfile2, line_1);
  getline(myfile2, line_2);
  getline(myfile2, line_3);
  getline(myfile2, line_4);

  myfile2.clear();
  myfile2.seekg(0, ios::beg);

  myfile2
    << md << '\n'
    << line_2 << '\n'
    << line_3 << '\n'
    << line_4 << '\n';
  myfile2.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works fine @Hal Canary !, no problem with the kilobytes, but why define excessively large the length of line_1,2,3,4 ?. THanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change the declaration of `l1` to:

```
char l1 [13];
```

`detectoroff` is 11 characters. You need another character for the newline, and another for the null byte that indicates the end of the string, which is 13 total. Since you only declared `l1` with 12 characters, `fgets()` was writing outside the array bounds. This results in undefined behavior.

Use `std::string` and C++ stream methods and you won't run into problems like this.

Comment: sorry about the Sleep(), I didn't delete it from the original code.

Comment: I didn't say anything about Sleep(), that's a comment in Mooing Duck's sample.